# Complexity vs Space in Schematic

Tags: design, eaglecad

I got a screw terminal with the following pin configuration:

```
X1
+-------------+
| (X) (X) (X) |       1 = 24V    2 = SIGNAL    3 = 0V
|  |   |   |  |
+--|---|---|--+
   1   2   3
```

My "requirements":

- Convert 24V SIGNAL to 12V logic
- Add bypass capacitor for supply

At the moment my schematic looks like this:

[image: Example schematic]

I need the design as compact as possible **but I don't want to confuse myself in future**.

What do you think: is the above schematic easy understandable or is it already too complex?
And what is commonly more important in a schematic: simplicity or sheet "space"?

Comment: Looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: You can add a layer for notes to the schematic. Just use it to write some comments to yourself in the future. We do it with code, there is no reason not to do it with schematics too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As drawn, there's no doubt about how things connect.
If you'd like to make it more obvious what is going on then I'd draw one of these two ways:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFZHAu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Electrically, it is the same.  From looking, though, it is obvious that you have a voltage divider on the Signal line and that your capacitor does nothing but bypass the 24Volts.

The second is a little more compact, but the divider is still obvious.

In the end, it usually comes down to how much room you have to fiddle with when drawing your diagram.  Sometimes you have to squeeze something in, then you place the parts where they'll fit.  But, in general try to follow conventions when placing parts in the diagram as it makes it that much easier to read for the next guy (who may be you in a couple of years.)

Clarity is the deciding factor.  The clearer, the better.  Sometimes this even means using less space on the diagram by logically grouping things instead of having connections run every which way.

Answer (score 4):

The schematic you show is just fine.

In general, more sheets is only a minor concern, and certainly way down the priority list relative to clarity.  In fact, breaking schematics into multiple sheets can help in the same way we break down a long narrative into paragraphs.  You can then label each sheet with the particular section of the circuit it shows, like the power supply, main controller, RS-232 interface, motor driver H bridge, etc.

I go into more detail on good schematic practices at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/28255/4512.

Comment: Just want to thank you for the link Olin. Good stuff! I just had to share it on a couple of electronics forums I'm a member of. Don't worry, I mentioned your name =)